# How to configure Farsun USB barcode scanner to not auto-trigger

Tags: usb, barcode-scanner

At my company we have several USB barcode scanners.  I'm not sure exactly what model they are, but I think they are the [FG9800 from Farsun](http://farsun.en.alibaba.com/product/436331512-210071500/FG9800_laser_barcode_scanner.html?tracelog=cgsotherproduct1) because that's what they look like on the exterior.  They came with a programming manual that is very similar to [this document](http://www.farsun.cn/Upfiles/D%E7%89%88%E8%AF%B4%E6%98%8E%E4%B9%A6%EF%BC%88%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%EF%BC%89.pdf) from the Farsun website.

When I scan the "Output Firmware Version" barcode, my scanner types the following into the computer:

```
  Farsun    V2.00    2011-01-01
```

**Is it possible to configure these scanners so they only read barcodes in response to the trigger button being pressed?  I don't want them to automatically read barcodes.**  Additionally, I want this setting to be remembered while the scanner is turned off.

Since this scanner only has a USB port, the only way to configure it that I know of is to scan bar codes from the manual (or make your own).  I have tried scanning the configuration bar codes for *Single Scan* (013300), *Single Scan No Trigger* (013301), and *Laser/CCD Timeout - 5 Seconds* (0134005) from [this document](http://www.adesso.com/productmanuals/UserGuide_NuScan_3000.pdf).  Sometimes (but not often) this puts the scanner in to the right mode, where it only scans when the button is pressed.  Unfortunately, the scanner seems to always leave this mode when it is power cycled.

I have also scanned the "Reset Configuration To Defaults" barcode (0B) many times.

We have three different scanners like this and I have not been able to successfully configure any of them.

If the things I want are not possible with these Farsun-based scanners, is there some other scanner we can use?

Comment: There should be a "save configuration" barcode that will permanently save what you have edited. I had it with one of my cheap barcode scanners.

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the scan button until the green light comes on. This puts mine into trigger mode rather than auto mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same barcode scanner. On the manual, the page 12 has a list of barcodes with title "Reading Mode". On there, try scanning Laser/CCD Mode - Single Scan No Trigger. That should do the trick.

Comment: I think I tried that.  What is the actual code that you used?  It should be printed below the barcode.  Sometimes (but not often) this puts the scanner in to the right mode, where it only scans when the button is pressed. Unfortunately, the scanner seems to always leave this mode when it is power cycled.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for your scanner, I don't have an exact model on my farsun scanner but the output firmware gives me this output.

> Firmware v1.0  Checksum=4712  11/29/01

In the programming manual I have it says you need the FNC3 character + 0 + the option number to change, in this case 133 + and the new value for the option 00 will turn it off (05 will turn it back on)

> so FNC3013300 would be your bar code, where FNC3 is the "code 128 program character"

I used P-Touch to make this bar code label, it is a label making program by Brother for its label printers.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtEn0.jpg

After you scan the label it should beep indicating that it has set the new value, it should also save that programming during power cycles as well, it does for me anyways.

You should also be able to program it to do whatever you need it to, I have made several programming bar codes from the manual to change the option(s) for what program that I happen to be using.